# iOS - Scale and crop CMSampleBufferRef/CVImageBufferRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation, cmsamplebufferref

I am using AVFoundation and getting the sample buffer from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, I can write it directly to videoWriter by using:

```
- (void)writeBufferFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
    CMTime lastSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);    
    if(self.videoWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting)
    {
        [self.videoWriter startWriting];
        [self.videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:lastSampleTime];
    }

    [self.videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

}
```

What I want to do now is to crop and scale the image inside the CMSampleBufferRef without converting it into UIImage or CGImageRef because that slows down the performance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use vimage you can work directly on the buffer data without converting it to any image format.

`outImg` contains the cropped and scaled image data. The relation between `outWidth` and `cropWidth` sets the scaling.
[image: vimage cropping]

```
int cropX0, cropY0, cropHeight, cropWidth, outWidth, outHeight;

CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);                   
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
                                    
vImage_Buffer inBuff;                       
inBuff.height = cropHeight;
inBuff.width = cropWidth;
inBuff.rowBytes = bytesPerRow;

int startpos = cropY0*bytesPerRow+4*cropX0;
inBuff.data = baseAddress+startpos;

unsigned char *outImg= (unsigned char*)malloc(4*outWidth*outHeight);
vImage_Buffer outBuff = {outImg, outHeight, outWidth, 4*outWidth};

vImage_Error err = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&inBuff, &outBuff, NULL, 0);
if (err != kvImageNoError) NSLog(@" error %ld", err);
```

So setting `cropX0 = 0` and `cropY0 = 0` and `cropWidth` and `cropHeight` to the original size means no cropping (using the whole original image). Setting `outWidth = cropWidth` and `outHeight = cropHeight` results in no scaling. Note that `inBuff.rowBytes` should always be the length of the full source buffer, not the cropped length.

Comment: Hi Sten, I searched the guide for a cropping example but couldn't fine one, can u give an example how to crop the buffer directly?

Comment: vImage has no cropping functionality

Comment: It is correct that vimage doesn't have a dedicated cropping function. But by setting the size of the buffer you can apply a crop together with essentially any function, e.g. a scale. I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Thank you so much man for this!! i spent the last day trying to figure out why i am getting a distorted cropped image. It turned out that the inBuff.rowBytes value i was setting was incorrect. I was recalculating it for the crop area rather than using the original one for the buffer

Comment: I know this question/answer is old, but how do I get the outBuff now to a CMSampleBuffer?

Comment: Nils, the data of the cropped file is in outImg. So you can use that to create a pixelbuffer e.g. with CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes. Then you can use that to create the CMSampleBuffer.

Comment: Hi @Sten , sorry to hijack this question but, I got a couple of questions related to this. First, if i am using the 'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection...' call to get a picture which i want to crop and rotate would it be more efficient to use vImage or CoreImage? (The end result should be an UIImage) But the process has to be very efficient because the system is killing my app for using too much memory too fast. Also, can i rotate and crop in a single operation using vImage? Thank you.

Comment: @Chiquis, to rotate and crop use the code above but use vImageRotate_ARGB8888 instead of vImageScale_ARGB8888. (Sorry for slow reply)

Comment: Hi, the "vImage Programming Guide" is not available in PDF format any more, and there is no "p10-12". Searching through the online version for "crop" didn't uncover anything. Has this been removed, or did I misunderstand the RTFM suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I have added an image instead of the link to the old PDF-guide.

Comment: @Sten the vImage operation is scrambling my image. Even when I set all the parameters so that it's simply a pass through, all inputs sizes = output sizes. can't seem to make sense of this.

Comment: @Gukki5 It is difficult to say without seeing your code. Are you sure that you are using the right row length and encoding when you convert the outImg to an image. Also, the code above assumes that the buffer is rgb not yuv.

Comment: @Sten basically i was using it to crop 4:3 aspect ratio to 16:9. So constant height, just shrinking the width. I was calculating the correct bytes per row for the resulting vImage_Buffer... but when I tried to use that for the input vImage_Buffer as well.. it was getting scrambled. When I switched to using the actual bytes per row of the input, it outputted fine. Haha now my issue is trying to properly get it into a CVPixelBuffer.

Comment: @Sten i'd thought the input bytes per row needed to correspond to the reduced image i was inputting, not the full image... since I was explicitly discarding some of it.

Comment: @Gukki5 The buffer is one long list of data so it needs the length of full image to know where "row breaks" are. To get a CVPixelBuffer you can try CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes

Comment: This code does not work/compile in iOS, the line "inBuff.data = baseAddress+startpos;" gives the compile error "arithmetic on pointer to void" and on "vImage_Buffer outBuff = {outImg, outHeight, outWidth, 4*outWidth};" the error "non-constant expression cannot be narrowed"

Comment: I am getting distorted output video, can any one help me.. I am using equivalent swift code. var srcBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: baseAddress! + startpos, height: UInt(destSize.height), width: UInt(destSize.width), rowBytes: Int(bytesPerRow))
        
        let outImg = UnsafeMutablePointer<u_char>.allocate(capacity: 4 * Int(destSize.width) * Int(destSize.height))
        var destBuffer: vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer(data: outImg, height: vImagePixelCount(destSize.height), width: vImagePixelCount(destSize.width), rowBytes: 4 * Int(destSize.width))

Comment: I'm trying to record a portion of the screen and I'm using the same code. However, it doesn't seem to work. Here's my question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904676/need-help-in-screen-recording-a-part-of-the-screen-in-ios. I've uploaded full source to git hub. Can someone help?

Comment: I used this logic to scale the image to smaller size without cropping. I feel that the scaled image has poor quality. Did anyone else face this issue?

Comment: The last parameter in the vImageScale call is a flag where you can set "highQualityResampling" (check out the documentation)

Comment: @Sten, I am trying to implement the same in Swift, I am a bit stuck at converting the vImageBuffer to CVPixelbuffer. Do you know how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 11):

Note: I didn't notice that the original question also requested scaling. But anyways, for those who simply needs to crop CMSampleBuffer, here's the solution.

The buffer is simply an array of pixels, so you can actually process the buffer directly without using vImage. Code is written in Swift, but I think it's easy to find the Objective-C equivalent.

First, make sure your CMSampleBuffer is BGRA format. If not, the preset you use is probably YUV, and ruin the bytes per rows that will later be used.

```
dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
dataOutput.videoSettings = [
    String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): 
    NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
]
```

Then, when you get the sample buffer:

```
let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly)

let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
let cropWidth = 640
let cropHeight = 640
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
// now the cropped image is inside the context. 
// you can convert it back to CVPixelBuffer 
// using CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes if you want.

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly)

// create image
let cgImage: CGImage = context!.makeImage()!
let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

If you want to crop from some specific position, add the following code:

```
// calculate start position
let bytesPerPixel = 4
let startPoint = [ "x": 10, "y": 10 ]
let startAddress = baseAddress + startPoint["y"]! * bytesPerRow + startPoint["x"]! * bytesPerPixel
```

and change the `baseAddress` in `CGContext()` into `startAddress`. Make sure not to exceed the origin image width and height.

Comment: "...without converting it into UIImage or CGImageRef because that slows down the performance."

Comment: I did "crop and scale the image inside the CMSampleBufferRef without converting it into UIImage or CGImageRef ". I just save it as CGImageRef for further usage (eg. show on screen). You can do whatever you want with the cropped context.

Comment: Hi 黃昱嘉 what is the best way to contact you? Would like to ask a quick question. Thanks!

Comment: Works great!  I am using this code to convert a 4:3 sample buffer to 16:9 with swift 2.2.  Huge thanks!

Comment: Update for Swift 3? It looks like the `CGBitmapContextCreate` function no longer exists...

Comment: @HighFlyingFantasy Sorry for the late response. I've edited my answer.

Comment: and how to convert CIImage back to CMSampleBuffer fast?

Comment: Hi, @yuji thank you for your answer! 
Could you please show how to recreate CVPixelBuffer? there is a lot of params I don't understand when trying to do it. 
And I would be super grateful if you could advice anything to read about all this magic

Answer (score 9):

You might consider using CoreImage (5.0+).

```
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                                           options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], kCIImageColorSpace, nil]];
ciImage = [[ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:myScaleTransform] imageByCroppingToRect:myRect];
```

Comment: and then, how can I convert it back to CMSampleBuffer, or how can I write it down using self.videoWriterInput?

Comment: CIContext has methods to rasterize a CIImage back into a CVPixelBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this on Swift3**

```
func resize(_ destSize: CGSize)-> CVPixelBuffer? {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) else { return nil }
        // Lock the image buffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        // Get information about the image
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer))
        let height = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
        let width = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer))
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        let options = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey:true,
                       kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey:true]
        let topMargin = (height - destSize.height) / CGFloat(2)
        let leftMargin = (width - destSize.width) * CGFloat(2)
        let baseAddressStart = Int(bytesPerRow * topMargin + leftMargin)
        let addressPoint = baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(destSize.width), Int(destSize.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, &addressPoint[baseAddressStart], Int(bytesPerRow), nil, nil, options as CFDictionary, &pixelBuffer)
        if (status != 0) {
            print(status)
            return nil;
        }
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        return pixelBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a distorted output video. do you know why

Answer (score 1):

For scaling you can have AVFoundation do this for you. See my recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394935/avassetwriterinput-impossible-to-choose-video-resolution/8514509#8514509). Setting the value for AVVideoWidth/AVVideoHeight key will scale the images if they are not the same dimensions. Take a look at the properties [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html).As for cropping I am not sure if you can have AVFoundation do this for you. You may have to resort to using OpenGL or CoreImage. There are a couple of good links in the top post for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895856/pixel-formats-cvpixelbufferrefs-and-glreadpixels).

Comment: I can make it automatically scale for me, but it keeps complaining me running out of memory, as you can look at my newest post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561456/ios-automatically-resize-cvpixelbufferref . It seems that reason is I keep changing the size