# iOS - Automatically resize CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation, cmsamplebufferref

I am trying to crop and scale a `CMSampleBufferRef` based on user's inputs, on `ratio`, the below code takes a CMSampleBufferRef, convert it into a CVImageBufferRef and use CVPixelBuffer to crop the internal image based on its bytes. The goal of this process is to have a cropped and scaled CVPixelBufferRef to write to the video

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)modifyImage:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer {
    @synchronized (self) {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
        // Lock the image buffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 

        // Get information about the image
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

        CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer;
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,  
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:720], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey, 
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:1280], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                 nil];
        NSInteger tempWidth = (NSInteger) (width / ratio);
        NSInteger tempHeight = (NSInteger) (height / ratio);

        NSInteger baseAddressStart = 100 + 100 * bytesPerRow;
        CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, tempWidth, tempHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, &baseAddress[baseAddressStart], bytesPerRow, MyPixelBufferReleaseCallback, NULL, (CFDictionaryRef)options, &pxbuffer);

        if (status != 0) {
            CKLog(@"%d", status);
            return NULL;
        }

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        return pxbuffer;
    }
}
```

It all works fine, except that when I am trying to write it into the video's ouput using this method, it keeps receiving memory warning. It is fine if I keep the same ratio

```
- (void)writeBufferFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer pixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer {
    CMTime lastSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);    

    if(self.videoWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting)
    {
        CKLog(@"%d", self.videoWriter.status);
        [self.videoWriter startWriting];
        [self.videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:lastSampleTime];
    }

    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = [self modifyImage:sampleBuffer];
    BOOL success = [self.avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pxbuffer withPresentationTime:lastSampleTime];
    if (!success)
        NSLog(@"Warning:  Unable to write buffer to video");
}
```

I also tried with different approaches using [CMSampleBufferRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493583/ios-scale-and-crop-cmsamplebufferref-cvimagebufferref) and [CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501149/crop-and-scale-cgcontext-ios). If you can provide a solution for any approach here, I can give you the full score

Comment: Small doubt i just want to resize CVpixcelbuffer . which is possible ? i just used your code . but couln't get it expected o/p.in option dic i have added original size and temp size i have pointed my expecetd size but which is not worked

Answer (score 1):

Try to use kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly flag in both calls to -CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress and -CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress.
And sometimes this issue can be solved by copying pixel buffer. Perform allocating once:

```
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)malloc(ySize * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

After that, copy data from pixelBuffer to data

> size_t size = height * bytesPerRow;
>
> memcpy(data, baseAddress, size);

After that, use data. Hope, that will help.

Comment: But I need to write my pixelBuffer to the video, how can I do that with `data`?

Comment: What abput sample code? Anyway, you're creating pixel buffer with CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, tempWidth, tempHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, &baseAddress[baseAddressStart], bytesPerRow, MyPixelBufferReleaseCallback, NULL, (CFDictionaryRef)options, &pxbuffer);

Comment: Yeah, I am creating a pixel buffer with that. I just don't get your suggestion over what I should do now

Comment: @nikita Can you help me regarding the problem of memory while creating a video ..