# How to go from vImage_Buffer to CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: ios, vimage

I'm recording live video in my iOS app. On another Stack Overflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493583/ios-scale-and-crop-cmsamplebufferref-cvimagebufferref), I found that you can use `vImage_Buffer` to work on my frames.

The problem is that I have no idea how to get back to a `CVPixelBufferRef` from the outputted `vImage_buffer`.

Here is the code that is given in the other article:

```
NSInteger cropX0 = 100,
          cropY0 = 100,
          cropHeight = 100,
          cropWidth = 100,
          outWidth = 480,
          outHeight = 480;

CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);                   
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

vImage_Buffer inBuff;                       
inBuff.height = cropHeight;
inBuff.width = cropWidth;
inBuff.rowBytes = bytesPerRow;

int startpos = cropY0 * bytesPerRow + 4 * cropX0;
inBuff.data = baseAddress + startpos;

unsigned char *outImg = (unsigned char*)malloc(4 * outWidth * outHeight);
vImage_Buffer outBuff = {outImg, outHeight, outWidth, 4 * outWidth};

vImage_Error err = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&inBuff, &outBuff, NULL, 0);
if (err != kvImageNoError) NSLog(@" error %ld", err);
```

And now I need to convert `outBuff` to a `CVPixelBufferRef`.

I assume I need to use `vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer`, but I'm not sure how.

My first attempts failed with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS: CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);`

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, 480, 480, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
    
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    
vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
    .bitsPerComponent = 8,
    .bitsPerPixel = 32,
    .bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst,  //BGRX8888
    .colorSpace = NULL,  //sRGB
};
    
vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer(&outBuff,
                                 &format,
                                 pixelBuffer,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                 kvImageNoFlags);  // Here is the crash!
    
    
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

Any idea?

Comment: To which chunk of bytes does the EXC_BAD_ACCESS correspond? The vImage_Buffer.data or the CVPixelBufferRef base address?

Comment: HI Ian, how exactly can I find that out?

Comment: Run your code in the debugger.  When you crash, you should see something like "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=X, address=ADDR)".  At that point, use the debugger to look at the values of pixelBuffer and outBuff.data.  One of them should be the same as or close to ADDR.

Comment: (This is assuming that you're actually crashing in CopyToCVPixelBuffer, and not earlier; what function are you crashing in?)

Comment: Well, the debugger holds at vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer but the addr is actually 0x0, but all input arguments outBuff,format and pixelBuffer are something different to 0x0.  The code is 1

Comment: Seems worthy of a bug report if you have a small reproducible code example. It could be that the NULL color space or background color didn't get handled correctly or something.  Maybe the new pixel buffer did something unexpected.

Comment: A crash report log would be handy too, in case it doesn't reproduce.

Comment: No, sorry :/ I stopped looking after a few hours of research

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool : YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool : YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt : 480], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt : 480], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
    nil];

status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      480,
                                      480,
                                      kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                      outImg,
                                      bytesPerRow,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options,
                                      &pixbuffer);
```

You should generate a new `pixelBuffer` like above.

Answer (score 1):

- Just in case... if you want a *cropped* live video feed into your interface, use an `AVPlayerLayer`, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and/or other `CALayer` subclasses, use the layer bounds, frame and position for your 100x100 pixel area to 480x480 area.

Notes for `vImage` for your question (different circumstances may differ):

1. `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` will not work with `vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer()` because you need to copy the `vImage_Buffer` data into a "clean" or "empty" `CVPixelBuffer`.
2. No need for locking/unlocking - make sure you know when to lock & when not to lock pixel buffers.
3. Your `inBuff` `vImage_Buffer` just needs to be initialized from the pixel buffer data, not manually (unless you know how to use `CGContext`s etc, to init the pixel grid)
4. use `vImageBuffer_InitWithCVPixelBuffer()`
5. `vImageScale_ARGB8888` will scale the entire CVPixel data to a smaller/larger rectangle. It won't SCALE a portion/crop area of the buffer to another buffer.
6. When you use `vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer()`,
   `vImageCVImageFormatRef` & `vImage_CGImageFormat` need to be filled out correctly.

   ```
   CGColorSpaceRef dstColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceITUR_709);

   vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
       .bitsPerComponent = 16,
       .bitsPerPixel = 64,
       .bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast  |  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big ,
       .colorSpace = dstColorSpace
   };
   vImageCVImageFormatRef vformat = vImageCVImageFormat_Create(kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16,
                                                               kvImage_ARGBToYpCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2,
                                                               kCVImageBufferChromaLocation_Center,
                                                               format.colorSpace,
                                                               0);

   CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         480,
                                         480,
                                         kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16,
                                         NULL,
                                         &destBuffer);

   NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && destBuffer != NULL);

   err = vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer(&sourceBuffer, &format, destBuffer, vformat, 0, kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole);
   ```

NOTE: these are settings for 64 bit ProRes with Alpha - adjust for 32 bit.

Comment: DON'T forget NB, NB, very NB - Memory Leak City
1. You must RELEASE CG objects yourself ( colorspace etc )

Comment: 2. You MUST also free(whatEver.data) from your buffers. None of these functions support ARC and if you are dealing with many video frames, you will soon run to a grinding halt.

Comment: Hi Paul, can you please answer my SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904676/need-help-in-screen-recording-a-part-of-the-screen-in-ios), it's related to this answer and I'm not sure how to do it in swift.