# Change camera resolution if I have width and height in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, opentok, tokbox

I need to change live video resolution with the width and height inputted by user. Sorry for my question but I have never done it before.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, You can change resolution of video. Look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You can change video resolution by using `AVMutableVideoComposition` and `AVAssetExportSession`.

First create object of `AVMutableVideoComposition` shown below.

```
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(YOUR_WIDTH, YOUR_HEIGHT);
```

Then, create object of `AVAssetExportSession`,

```
exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

And write completionBlock for exporter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can try this code. You have to just provide `width`,`height` and `asset`. Try some code and let me know.

Comment: i m only playing a video so what will be asset here?

Comment: An url of video will be asset here.

Comment: i m playing a live video. so i dont have its url. I need to do it using AVCaptureSession.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenTok, you can use a custom video capturer that is mostly identical to the one found in [this sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/blob/develop/2.Lets-Build-OTPublisher/Lets-Build-OTPublisher/TBExampleVideoCapture.m#L303). The only difference is that you would need to additionally write code to scale the image from the CVPixelBuffer (called `imageBuffer`) to the size  which your user is setting.

One way technique to scale the image would be to use the CoreImage APIs as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494304/305340

Comment: can you please explain a little more?

Comment: @user I'm not sure what you need me to explain. Have you looked at the linked sample? Have you understood the linked scaling technique? Do you have any more specific questions regarding those?