# Convert CVPixelBufferRef sample from 4:3 to 16:9

Tags: image, avfoundation, crop, cmsamplebuffer

I try to convert 4:3 frame to 16:9 frame in the video capture pipeline. And converted frame would need further processing. Therefore I need to keep covered frame as `CVImageBufferRef`.
I looked at this stack overflow thread, and borrow some idea from it
[iOS - Scale and crop CMSampleBufferRef/CVImageBufferRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493583/ios-scale-and-crop-cmsamplebufferref-cvimagebufferref)

here is what I did:

```
int cropX0 = 0, cropY0 = 60, cropHeight = 360, cropWidth = 640, outWidth = 640, outHeight = 360;
//get CVPixel buffer from CMSampleBuffer
CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(cmSampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

size_t startpos = cropY0 * bytesPerRow;
void* cropStartAddr = ((char*)baseAddress) + startpos;

CVPixelBufferRef cropPixelBuffer = NULL;
int status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          outWidth,
                                          outHeight,
                                          CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer),
                                          cropStartAddr,
                                          bytesPerRow,
                                          NULL, 
                                          0,
                                          NULL, 
                                          &cropPixelBuffer);
if(status == 0){
    OSStatus result = 0;
}
```

But after this method. if we inspect the cropPixelBuffer from Xcode. it looks like a corrupt image.

[image]
The original picture looks like this

[image]

I think it could be because of the color format is NV12 yuv pixel format
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If your image data is yuv, then you might to deal with multiple plane data (e.g. multiple `rowbytes`, multiple `baseAddrs` and multiple `width`,`height`s and multiple crops) in which case you would have to use

```
CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes()
```

so what does `CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer)` return?

Comment: format is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange. I think I need to handing UV separately

Comment: Yes, that means you have two bit maps to crop