# AVAssetWriter: Using an alternate encoding

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession

I have written an application to step through (and alter) each frame of a video using AVFramework's AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter. It works great, but I need to be able to encode the video to MPEG4. 
Is there a way to change the output encoding for AVAssetWriter to something other then H264?
If not, is there a way I can use AVAssetExportSession with AVAssetWriter (without writing to a temporary file)?

Is there a better way to be doing this all together?

The application needs to read a source video, process every frame and write out to either H264 or MPEG4. (OSX)

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394935/avassetwriterinput-impossible-to-choose-video-resolution/8514509#8514509). You need to setup the properties to AVAssetWriter.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but this example still has the codec set to H.264 (AVVideoCodecH264). I'm trying to have the video encoded into a different format.